# Laminas/Zend Test that user is redirected if form is valid

Tags: phpunit, mockery, laminas

I'm trying to write a test that checks if a user is redirected if the form is valid. In order to do this, I mock my form and make it return true when isValid is called.

But I get the following errors:

1. UserTest\Controller\RegisterControllerTest::testRegisterPageCanBeAccessed
   foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
   /home/razvbir/PhpstormProjects/expenses.money/vendor/laminas/laminas-form/src/Fieldset.php:302

/home/razvbir/PhpstormProjects/expenses.money/module/User/test/Controller/RegisterControllerTest.php:94

2. UserTest\Controller\RegisterControllerTest::testRegisterPageRedirectsAfterCreatingNewUser

- foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
  /home/razvbir/PhpstormProjects/expenses.money/vendor/laminas/laminas-form/src/Fieldset.php:357
- foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
  /home/razvbir/PhpstormProjects/expenses.money/vendor/laminas/laminas-form/src/Fieldset.php:302

/home/razvbir/PhpstormProjects/expenses.money/module/User/test/Controller/RegisterControllerTest.php:122

How can I fix this? Or is there another way to write this test?

This is my test code:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace UserTest\Controller;

use Laminas\Form\FormElementManager;
use Laminas\Http\Request;
use Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Laminas\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Laminas\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;
use Mockery;
use Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\MockeryPHPUnitIntegration;
use Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\MockeryTestCaseSetUp;
use User\Form\RegisterForm;

class RegisterControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    use MockeryPHPUnitIntegration;
    use MockeryTestCaseSetUp;

    protected $traceError = true;

    protected Mockery\MockInterface $registerForm;
    protected Mockery\MockInterface $formElementManager;
    protected function mockeryTestSetUp() {}

    protected function mockeryTestTearDown() {}

    protected function configureServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager): void
    {
        $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);

        $serviceManager->setService('config', $this->overrideConfig($serviceManager->get('config')));
        $serviceManager->setService(FormElementManager::class, $this->formElementManager);

        $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(false);
    }

    protected function overrideConfig(array $config): array
    {
        $testConfigOverrides = include __DIR__ . '/../../../../config/test.config.php';

        return ArrayUtils::merge($config, $testConfigOverrides);
    }

    protected function mockRegisterForm(): void
    {
        $this->registerForm = Mockery::mock(RegisterForm::class)->makePartial();
        $this->registerForm
            ->shouldReceive('isValid')
            ->andReturnTrue();

        $this->registerForm
            ->shouldReceive('getData')
            ->andReturn([
                'email' => 'example@pm.me',
                'password' => 'parolameasuperba1'
            ]);
    }

    protected function mockFormElementManager(): void
    {
        $this->formElementManager =  Mockery::mock(FormElementManager::class);
        $this->formElementManager
            ->makePartial()
            ->shouldReceive('get')
            ->with(RegisterForm::class)
            ->andReturn($this->registerForm);
    }

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $applicationConfigOverrides = [];

        $this->setApplicationConfig(ArrayUtils::merge(
            include __DIR__ . '/../../../../config/application.config.php',
            $applicationConfigOverrides
        ));

        parent::setUp();

        $this->mockRegisterForm();
        $this->mockFormElementManager();

        $this->configureServiceManager($this->getApplicationServiceLocator());
    }

    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testRegisterPageCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/user/register');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->assertModuleName('user');
        $this->assertControllerName('User\Controller\RegisterController');
        $this->assertControllerClass('RegisterController');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('user/register/expose');

        $this->assertQuery('form#registerForm[method="POST"]');

        $this->assertQuery('form#registerForm label[for="email"]');
        $this->assertQuery('form#registerForm input[name="email"]');

        $this->assertQuery('form#registerForm label[for="password"]');
        $this->assertQuery('form#registerForm input[name="password"]');

        $this->assertQuery('form#registerForm label[for="confirm-password"]');
        $this->assertQuery('form#registerForm input[name="confirm-password"]');

        $this->assertQuery('form#registerForm input[type="submit"]');
    }

    /**
     * @group optional
     */
    public function testRegisterPageRedirectsAfterCreatingNewUser()
    {
        $this->registerForm
            ->shouldReceive('isValid')
            ->once()
            ->andReturnTrue();

        $this->dispatch('/user/register', Request::METHOD_POST);
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(303);
        $this->assertRedirect();
    }
}
```

and here is the controller:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace User\Controller;

use Laminas\Form\Form;
use Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use User\Model\UserCommandInterface;
use User\Model\User;

class RegisterController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function __construct(
        protected Form $form,
        protected UserCommandInterface $command
    ) {}

    public function exposeRegisterAction(): array
    {
        return [
            'form' => $this->form
        ];
    }

    public function processRegisterAction(): array
    {
        $this->form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());

        if ($this->form->isValid()) {
            $filteredData = $this->form->getData();

            $newUser = new User(email: $filteredData['email']);
            $newUser->setHashFromPlainText($filteredData['password']);

            $this->command->insertUser($newUser);

            $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
        }

        return [
            'form' => $this->form
        ];
    }
}
```